# Trying to get the "new markers" from list2

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two arrays and then alert the ones that are not in the first array but that are in the second one,  all this is doing is alerting everything....  Any ideas?

```
function doit(){
 var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
 var list2 = [2, 3, 4, 7];

    for (var i in list1) {
      for (var j in list2) {
        if (list2[j] != list1[i]) {
          alert(list2[j]);
            }
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: I ran this (using console.log) and it doesn't list 5 or 6. But see zerkms's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var diff = list2.filter(function(i) {
    return list1.indexOf(i) == -1;
});
```

Comment: wow, I can't believe I haven't came across the filter method.  Thank you, that did the trick.

Comment: What if the array had several attributes attached to each row?  Can I specify which attribute to compare to?  Say I had an 'ID' attribute that was unique to each row in both arrays?

Comment: @HondaKillrsx: only with iterating or flattening the array first (so that it was an array of strings like in your original question)